# capturing all dom manipulation events

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xmlhttprequest, mutation-observers

I'm trying to create a proxy JS so every request to external resource will be proxied like XHR or any other resource.
so for XHR request i manage to do it with this code:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    var XMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;

    var startTracing = function () {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.uniqueID = function() {
            // each XMLHttpRequest gets assigned a unique ID and memorizes it
            //  in the "uniqueIDMemo" property
            if (!this.uniqueIDMemo) {
                this.uniqueIDMemo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            }
            return this.uniqueIDMemo;
        }

        // backup original "open" function reference
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

        var newOpen = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
            //console.log(url);//new



            if (url.includes("somesample")) {
                //Debug Only
                /*console.log("[" + this.uniqueID() + "] intercepted open (" +
                 method + " , " +
                 url + " , " +
                 async + " , " +
                 user + " , " +
                 password + ")");*/
                urlParts = /^(?:\w+\:\/\/)?([^\/]+)(.*)$/.exec(url);
                hostname = urlParts[1]; // www.example.com
                path = urlParts[2]; // /path/to/somwhere
                proxyprefix = "http://myproxy.com/xhr.php?url="
                fullurl = "http://" + hostname + path;
                rewrittenUrl = proxyprefix + btoa(encodeURIComponent(fullurl));
                url = rewrittenUrl;
            }
            this.oldOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
        }

        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = newOpen;

        // backup original "send" function reference
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

        var newSend = function(a) {
            //console.log("[" + this.uniqueID() + "] intercepted send (" + a + ")");
            var xhr = this;
            var onload = function() {
                /*console.log("[" + xhr.uniqueID() + "] intercepted load: " +
                 xhr.status +
                 " " + xhr.responseText);*/
            };

            var onerror = function() {
                /* console.log("[" + xhr.uniqueID() + "] intercepted error: " +
                 xhr.status);*/
            };

            xhr.addEventListener("load", onload, false);
            xhr.addEventListener("error", onerror, false);

            this.oldSend(a);
        }
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
    }


    startTracing();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var ActualActiveXObject = ActiveXObject;

    var ActiveXObject = function(progid) {
        var ax = new ActualActiveXObject(progid);

        if (progid.toLowerCase() == "msxml2.xmlhttp") {

            var o = {
                _ax: ax,
                _status: "fake",
                responseText: "",
                responseXml: null,
                readyState: 0,
                status: 0,
                statusText: 0,
                onReadyStateChange: null
            };
            o._onReadyStateChange = function() {
                var self = o;
                return function() {
                    self.readyState   = self._ax.readyState;
                    if (self.readyState == 4) {
                        self.responseText = self._ax.responseText;
                        self.responseXml  = self._ax.responseXml;
                        self.status       = self._ax.status;
                        self.statusText   = self._ax.statusText;
                    }
                    if (self.onReadyStateChange) self.onReadyStateChange();
                }
            }();
            o.open = function(bstrMethod, bstrUrl, varAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword) {
                /*console.log("intercepted open (" +
                 bstrMethod + " , " +
                 bstrUrl + " , " +
                 varAsync + " , " +
                 bstrUser + " , " +
                 bstrPassword + ")");*/
                varAsync = (varAsync !== false);
                this._ax.onReadyStateChange = this._onReadyStateChange
                return this._ax.open(bstrMethod, bstrUrl, varAsync, bstrUser, bstrPassword);
            };
            o.send = function(varBody) {
                return this._ax.send(varBody);
            };
        }
        else
            var o = ax;
        return o;
    }
}
```

and its working fine.
and because i have got some js that manipulate the dom and adds elements i need to intercept that to.
so i started by rewriting appendChild with that code:

```
window.callbackFunc = function(elem, args) {
    //console.log(elem);

    for (var key in elem) {


        if (elem.hasOwnProperty(key) && elem[key].src)
        {
            elem[key].src = "http://myptoxy/proxy.php?u=" +encodeURIComponent(elem[key].src);

        }
    }


}
window.f = Element.prototype.appendChild;

Element.prototype.appendChild = function() {
    window.callbackFunc.call(this, arguments);
    return window.f.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

and thats also working well but i encounter a problem with createlement.

some js code on my site creates an iframe with src that i'm unable to intercept with this code:

```
document.createElement = function(create) {
    return function() {
        var ret = create.apply(this, arguments);


        //console.log(ret);
        for (var key in ret) {

            if (ret.hasOwnProperty(key) && ret[key].src) {

                ret[key].src = "http://myproxy.com/proxy.php?u=" + encodeURIComponent(elem[key].src);
            }
        }

        return ret;
    };
}(document.createElement)
```

I mean I can intercept the creation but the attributes are empty obviously the script adds the attribute after the element creation)

I tried to use MutationObserver but with no luck...

Any help?
Another approach  to the entire problem will be great!

Comment: `some js code on my site creates an iframe` - can you show this code?

Comment: The code is obfuscated so I didn’t bother trying to debug it. But when I console.log the element after I intercepted the createelement I can see the iframe but no attributes so it doesn’t help me, it’s just prints <iframe></iframe> if I continue execution I can see all the attributes but at the moment of interception in the createElement function all I have is an empty iframe tags